# How to just show 4 digit year in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date

I found the [Angular Date documentation here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date), and thought the filter yyyy would be enough, but it's still attaching on the actual day.

My HTML:

```
<p class="footer_copy">&copy; {{ footer.date | date : yyyy }} AT&amp;T</p>
```

My Angular Directive for the footer, with a function to create a date:

```
// Directive for Footer
app.directive('appFooter', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'templates/app-footer.html',
        controller: function(){
            this.date = Date.now();
        },
        controllerAs:'footer'
    };
});
```

However right now it spits out **© Sep 24, 2014 AT&T**

I'd like it to just create **© 2014 AT&T**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use to pass the format as a string

```js
var app = angular.module('my-app', [], function() {})

app.directive('appFooter', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<p class="footer_copy">&copy; {{ footer.date | date:"yyyy" }} AT&amp;T</p>',
        controller: function(){
            this.date = Date.now();
        },
        controllerAs:'footer'
    };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="my-app">
  <app-footer></app-footer>
</div>
```

Another option is to pass the format as a variable like

```js
var app = angular.module('my-app', [], function() {})

app.directive('appFooter', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<p class="footer_copy">&copy; {{ footer.date | date:footer.dateFormat }} AT&amp;T</p>',
    controller: function() {
      this.date = Date.now();
      this.dateFormat = 'yyyy'
    },
    controllerAs: 'footer'
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="my-app">
  <app-footer></app-footer>
</div>
```

Comment: I can combine that Controller into my Directive correct? Would hate to waste a whole Controller just to spit out a date. How would they be combined into what I have now?

Comment: @LeonGaban yes.. you can

Comment: Ah I was missing quotes around my yyyy, 'yyyy' thanks! 4 mins